# Controller not loading Grid container Error: Class 'Mage_Reviewmycompany_Helper_Data

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, controllers, fatal-error

I have created a custom module one part is working fine that is adminform now i have create a grid to show all the data saved in database. But all i get is blank page.

Here is my **grid.php** file:

```
<?php

   class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Grid extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     {


      public function __construct()
       {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->setId('reviewGrid');
         $this->setDefaultSort('id_optfirst_reviewmycompany');
         $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
         $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
       }

      protected function _prepareCollection()
       {
         $collection = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->getCollection();
         //print_r($collection);
         $this->setCollection($collection);
         return parent::_prepareCollection();
       }

      protected function _prepareColumns()
       {
         $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optFirst_reviewMyCompany')->__('Facebook'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optFirst_reviewMyCompany')->__('Google'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'name',
        'width' => '50px',
        ));


    $this->addColumn('content', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optFirst_reviewMyCompany')->__('Twitter'),
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'content',
        ));
      return parent::_prepareColumns();
     }
   }
```

And here is my controller:

```
  <?php

       class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Adminhtml_ReviewController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
        {

          public functio  indexAction() {
            $this->loadLayout();
            $this->renderLayout();

        }
       public function gridAction()
        {
         $this->loadLayout();
         $this->getResponse()->setBody(
         $this->getLayout()->createBlock('optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_review_grid')->toHtml()
         );
        }
       }
```

And here is my **confix.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
<modules>
    <OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block</class>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper</class>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
    </helpers>

    <models>         
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource</resourceModel>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
            <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <review>
                    <table>optfirst_reviewmycompany</table>
                </review>
            </entities>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_resource>
    </models>

    <resource>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_setup>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_write>
        <optfirst_reviewmycompany_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </optfirst_reviewmycompany_read>
    </resource>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <optfirst_reviewmycompany after="Mage_Adminhtml">OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Adminhtml</optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                <file>optfirst_reviewmycompany.xml</file>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        </updates>
        <updates>
            <review>
                <file>review.xml</file>
            </review>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
                <files>
                    <default>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany.csv</default>
                </files>
            </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>

<default>
    <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <general>
            <default_sort_by><![CDATA[position]]></default_sort_by>
        </general>
    </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
</default>
```

My Helper Class in **OptFirst/ReviewMyCompany/Helper/Data.php**

```
     <?php
      class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
         {

         }
```

[image]

Can you please check what is wrong and why its not showing the grid container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After review you coding there were three mistake in that

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <menu>
        <optfirst translate="title" module="optfirst_reviewmycompany">
            <title>Review My Company</title>
            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
            <children>
                <form translate="title" module="optfirst_reviewmycompany">
                    <title>Form</title>
                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/adminform</action>
                </form>
                  <items module="optfirst_reviewmycompany">
                        <title>Manage Social Icons</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>adminhtml/review/index</action>
                    </items>
            </children>
        </optfirst>
    </menu>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <all>
                <title>Allow Everything</title>
            </all>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <optfirst>
                        <title>Optfirst</title>
                        <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                        <children>
                            <form>
                                <title>Form</title>
                                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                            </form>
                        </children>
                    </optfirst>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

**optfirst_reviewmycompany.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0">

    <adminhtml_adminform_index>
        <update handle="editor"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_form_edit" name="adminform"/>
        </reference>
       <reference name="left">
            <block type="optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_form_edit_tabs" name="adminform_tabs"/>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_adminform_index>

    <adminhtml_review_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_review" name="review" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_review_index>

</layout>
```

**ReviewController.php**

```
<?php

class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Adminhtml_ReviewController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_action
{

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
                $this->renderLayout();               
    }

    public function gridAction()
    {  //this action is used for ajax request you are calling it directly


                $this->getResponse()->setBody(
                $this->getLayout()->createBlock('optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_review_grid')->toHtml()
                );

    }


 }
```

**Review.php**

```
<?php
class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Review extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_review';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'optfirst_reviewmycompany';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Review Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Add Review');
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

Comment: So indexAction is working fine, it is showing correct layout i have just echo a thing there. You change the action to index method but we need the action to gridAction method so it will show the grid page instead of showing index page..
@Qaisar Satti

Comment: @Xabby gridaction is used when you apply filter to gird then layout are update from gridaction. If you search in grid the while page is update only grid is update that time called the gridAction. I fully tested you code then gave you solution

Answer (score 4):

Your helpers calls in your Grid.php are wrong.

You need to replace:

```
Mage::helper('optFirst_reviewMyCompany')
```

With :

```
Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')
```

The value inside the `Mage::helper` method should match what you've declared in your `config.xml` in your case:

```
<helpers>
    <optfirst_reviewmycompany>
        <class>OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper</class>
    </optfirst_reviewmycompany>
</helpers>
```

Comment: I have tried with following solutions but still showing the same results also i have attached the screenshot of my screen that what it looks like:
1- Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Facebook'),
2- Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Facebook'),

Answer (score 1):

I thin you are missing the grid container

```
class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Review extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_review';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'review';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('test')->__('Review Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('advancecms')->__('Add Review');
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

that were called in

```
<adminhtml_review_grid>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="reviewMyCompany/adminhtml_review" name="review" />
    </reference>
</adminhtml_review_grid>
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-new\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid\Container.php on line 66

Comment: @Xabby http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/setsaveparametersinsession-on-a-non-object look at this

Answer (score 0):

```
<? xml version = "1.0" ?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_reviewmycompany_review_grid>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="reviewmycompany/adminhtml_review_grid" name="review" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_reviewmycompany_review_grid>
</layout>
```

layout XML node

**adminRoute_moduleName_contromlerName_ActionName**

refers to route

**adminRoute/moduleName/contromlerName/ActionName**

So

```
<adminhtml_reviewmycompany_review_grid>
```

will refer to

**YOUR_ADMIN_ROUTE/reviewmycompany/review/grid**

and resolve to the following method

**OptFirst/ReviewMyCompany/Adminhtml/ReviewController -> gridAction**

Comment: When i just echo a string it shows but when i load grid it shows error here is my ReviewController.php
public function gridAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
         $this->renderLayout();
                echo "Hello";
       // $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            //$this->getLayout()->createBlock('optfirst_reviewmycompany/adminhtml_review_grid')->toHtml()
    //);
    }
 }

Comment: What's the error message say?

Comment: this is the error:
Class 'Mage_Reviewmycompany_Helper_Data' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento_dev\app\Mage.php on line 547 @Weaves81

Comment: So In your block you've called Mage::helper('reviewmycompany')->__('ID').

Does OptFirst/ReviewMyCompany/Helper/Data.php exist? If not just create it and extend Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract. it can just be an empty class.

Comment: the error is because of You have not added helper file in your module,  just create a file in helper folder with class name `OptFirst_Reviewmycompany_Helper_Data` extending `Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract`

Comment: I have already created..
<?php

class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}

Comment: Magento is looking for  OptFirst_Reviewmycompany_Helper_Data but you have OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Helper_Data.

If you change your calls to helper in your grid block to Mage::helper('reviewMyCompany')->__('ID') - note uppercase letters

Comment: So i have to defined like this?
Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewMyCompany')->__('ID'),

Comment: try this Mage::helper('optFirst_reviewMyCompany')->__('ID'),

Comment: Same issue i have updated the question with my latest Grid.php code @Weaves81

Comment: @Xabby can you also add the helper class

Comment: @Weaves81 Question is updated now with helper class please check. and also can you please check xml file too is there any issue with that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49152/discussion-between-weaves81-and-xabby).

Answer (score 0):

in your `grid.php` file helper is wrong in every where

please change your `grid.php` with below

```
<?php

   class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Grid extends
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
     {


      public function __construct()
       {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->setId('reviewGrid');
         $this->setDefaultSort('id_optfirst_reviewmycompany');
         $this->setDefaultDir('ASC');
         $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
       }

      protected function _prepareCollection()
       {
         $collection = Mage::getModel('optfirst_reviewmycompany/review')->getCollection();
         //print_r($collection);
         $this->setCollection($collection);
         return parent::_prepareCollection();
       }

      protected function _prepareColumns()
       {
         $this->addColumn('id', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Facebook'),
        'align' => 'right',
        'width' => '10px',
        'index' => 'id',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Google'),
        'align' => 'left',
        'index' => 'name',
        'width' => '50px',
        ));


    $this->addColumn('content', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Twitter'), 
        'width' => '150px',
        'index' => 'content',
        ));
      return parent::_prepareColumns();
     }
   }
```

Comment: Ok that is updated but still not any luck can you please check the Block section
class OptFirst_ReviewMyCompany_Block_Adminhtml_Review extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_review';
        $this->_blockGroup = 'review';
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Review Manager');
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('optfirst_reviewmycompany')->__('Add Review');
        parent::__construct();
    }

Comment: @Xabby after that change error is same or some different error you got

Comment: Its still not showing the correct layout of the Grid. its same as the screenshot attached above with the question