# Error in custom module Adminhtml Grid (setSaveParametersInSession() on boolean)

Tags: adminhtml, grid

I generated a module using this online tool: http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/

I am now facing this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on boolean in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php:66

But I don't know how I could debug it. Website is running on Magento CC 1.9.3. Saw this [setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10848/setsaveparametersinsession-on-a-non-object) and that [Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on a non-object in aBlock\Widget\Grid\Container.php on line 66](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33071/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-setsaveparametersinsession-on-a-non-obj) but don't see what I could change.

A dump in core's Container.php, on 
`$this->_blockGroup.'/'.$this->_controller.'_grid'`
returns me this:
`'destinataires/adminhtml_destinataireschauvinfrance_grid'`

Which seems right. Am I wrong?

An extract of my config.xml :

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Canalweb_Destinataires>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Canalweb_Destinataires>
  </modules>
  <global>
    […]
    <blocks>
      <destinataires>
        <class>Canalweb_Destinataires_Block</class>
      </destinataires>
    </blocks>
    <models>
      […]
      <destinataires>
        <class>Canalweb_Destinataires_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>destinataires_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </destinataires>
      <destinataires_mysql4>
        <class>Canalweb_Destinataires_Model_Mysql4</class>
        <entities>
          <destinataireschauvinfrance>
            <table>destinataires_chauvin_france</table>
          </destinataireschauvinfrance>  
          <destinataireschauvinpays>
            <table>destinataires_chauvin_pays</table>
          </destinataireschauvinpays>
          […]
        </entities>
      </destinataires_mysql4>
    </models>
    […]
    <admin>
      <routers>
        <destinataires>
          <use>admin</use>
          <args>
            <module>Canalweb_Destinataires</module>
            <frontName>admin_destinataires</frontName>
          </args>
        </destinataires>
      </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
      <menu>
        <destinataires module="destinataires">
        <title>Destinataires</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
          <destinataireschauvinfrance module="destinataires">
            <title>Manage Destinataireschauvinfrance</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
            <action>admin_destinataires/adminhtml_destinataireschauvinfrance</action>
          </destinataireschauvinfrance>
          […]
```

My Block/Adminhtml/Destinataireschauvinfrance.php :

```
<?php

class Canalweb_Destinataires_Block_Adminhtml_Destinataireschauvinfrance extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_controller = "adminhtml_destinataireschauvinfrance";
        $this->_blockGroup = "destinataires";
        $this->_headerText = Mage::helper("destinataires")->__("Destinataireschauvinfrance Manager");
        $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper("destinataires")->__("Add New Item");
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Beginning of my Block/Adminhtml/Destinataireschauvinfrance/Grid.php :

```
<?php

class Canalweb_Destinataires_Block_Adminhtml_Destinataireschauvinfrance_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setId("destinataireschauvinfranceGrid");
        $this->setDefaultSort("id");
        $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
        $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
    }
```

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state in your config.xml that the admin front name of your module is "admin_destinataires" but then you use "destinataires" as the blockgroup.

Try replacing

```
$this->_blockGroup = "destinataires";
```

with

```
$this->_blockGroup = "admin_destinataires";
```

==Edit==

The 'Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() on boolean' error is caused when  the grid container class/block cannot find the grid class/block. 
So my money is still at that the blockgroup you are using is wrong.

If the above does not solve your problem, try replacing all instances of admin_destinataires with destinataires.

Comment: Yes! Replacing all instances of admin_destinataires was the trick. Thank you very, very much!